# SharePoint online 2013 CSOM "cannot get contact site at specified url" error

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

When I am using the complete url, I get "cannot get contact site at specified url". When just the parent url like `https://mydomain.sharepoint.com`, then list item is created on on a list of main site address. Can anyone please help locate the desired site list content? Any help would be much appreciated. Please see code below:

```
string sharePointSiteUrl = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/site/test_site/Lists/list_items/AllItems.aspx"; // this is the complete address of already created list items. 
try
{ 
    using (ClientContext clc = new ClientContext(sharePointSiteUrl))
    {
        SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in "mypassword".ToCharArray())     passWord.AppendChar(c);
        clc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myuserid", passWord);
        clc.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

        List oList = clc.Web.List.ContentTypeExistsByName("List_name");
        ListItemCreationInformation listCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(listCreationInformation);
        oListItem["Title"] = "Add item in SharePoint List using CSOM";
        oListItem.Update();
        clc.ExecuteQuery();  
        Console.WriteLine("item added successfully");
        Console.ReadKey();  
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + ex.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `sharePointSiteUrl` variable should be only the site URL where the list is located, not the URL of the default list view of the list or the URL of the root site/site collection.

Your variable assignment should look like this: `string sharePointSiteUrl = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/site/test_site";`.